# Tiny Slider - Show exactly number of items in Responsive mode

Tags: html, css, shopware, tiny-slider

Hi i'm using Tiny Slider :
http://ganlanyuan.github.io/tiny-slider/

and i have a problem with Responsive Mode:

This is the code i currently using:

```html
 {% set productSliderOptions = {
                    productboxMinWidth: '100%',
                    slider: {
                        autoplayButtonOutput: false,
                        gutter:10,
                        nav: false,
                        mouseDrag: false,
                        viewportMax:true,
                        lazyload:true,
                        controls: sliderConfig.navigation.value ? true : false,
                        autoplay: sliderConfig.rotate.value ? true : false,
                        responsive: {
                            xs: {
                                gutter:5,
                                items: 2,
                                viewportMax:true,
                            },
                            sm: {
                                viewportMax:true,
                                items: 3
                            },
                            md: {
                                viewportMax:true,
                                items: 4
                            },
                            lg: {
                                gutter:30,
                                viewportMax:true,
                                items: 5
                            },
                            xl: {
                                gutter:30,
                                viewportMax:false,
                                items: 5
                            }
                        }


                         
                    }
                } %}
```

i want to show in xs exactly 2 products and in lg 5 and no more the problem here is tiny slider shows all the items:

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN1hQ.png)

i tried fixwidth too but it seems it's not responsive.

is there any way to show in the viewport exactly two products in xs and 5 products in lg and md?!

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are settings the viewportMax option to `true` but it expects only [false or a positive integer](http://ganlanyuan.github.io/tiny-slider/#options). This might cause problems.

Also please check if the slider is initialized at all - watch out for any JavaScript errors.